# How to deploy django web app to google cloud?

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, django-deployment, django-2.2

how can i deploy python/django web app to Google Cloud ? i am using django 2.2 and python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google cloud documentation has in-detail documentation on this specifically for python 3.7
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/